# How to call overloaded function using return value from other function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
     Option (abstract)
            ^
            |
     +------+-------+
     |              |
     +              +
 Something[T]    Nothing
```

Implementation is as follows:

```
class Option {
public:
    Option() {};
    virtual ~Option() {};

    virtual bool nothing() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Something : public Option
{
public:
    Something(T _value) : value(_value) {};
    virtual ~Something() {};

    const T value;
    virtual bool nothing() {return false;};
};

class Nothing : public Option
{
public:
    Nothing() {};
    virtual ~Nothing() {};

    virtual bool nothing() {return true;};
};
```

Now, I want to be able to write a function with the following signature:

```
is_nothing: Nothing& => True
is_nothing: Something[T]& => False
```

I have tried using templates in the following manner:

```
template <class T> bool is_nothing(Nothing&) {return true;};
template <class T> bool is_nothing(Something<T> &) {return false;};
```

and it does work when used like this:

```
is_nothing<int>(Nothing());
is_nothing<int>(Something<int>(4));
```

but does not want to compile due to missing `is_nothing: Option& => bool` when called like this
`is_nothing<int>(an_option())` where `an_option: void => Option&` actually returns an instance of `Nothing`. So to me it looks like it suddenly lost the ability to make polymorphic calls.

Code that uses `Option`:

```
Nothing n;

Option& an_option() {return n;};
int main(int argc,char** argv) 
{
    is_nothing<int>(an_option());
    return 0;
}
```

Please guide me to the right direction, because I feel something in this approach is wrong, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile, since you are binding non-const lvalue references to temporaries. Please post some realistic code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overload resolution is done in terms of the *static* type of the argument, not the *dynamic* (runtime) type. When you call `is_nothing<int>(an_option())` the compiler resolves `an_option()` to a function returning `Option&` and will try to resolve in terms of that type, not the type of the object bound by the reference.

If you explain the problem that you want to solve you might get some alternative design that works within the language. The simplest, generic approach, but at the same time one that is considered a code smell and I would not recommend, is using RTTI information to infer the actual type. In particular, the implementation of `is_nothing` could take a reference to `Option` and use RTTI (`dynamic_cast` or `typeid`) to determine what the dynamic type of the object is and act accordingly.

But this is a *bad* design, and you will get better alternatives if you explain in what context you need this and what you really want to solve.

Comment: Yeah I think you're trying to model your class too much like Scala's option, which has the benefit of being able to use reflection and other fancy type magic. Here's Boost's Option class in case you're interested http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp

Comment: Basically, the problem that has led me to this thinking is that I want to have a container interface that returns a reference to an object if its valid or a null object otherwise. The next step would be a possibility for a client to take advantage of dynamic dispatch to avoid the abominations you mention, i.e. RTTI.

The reason why I want to have my own interface instead of maybe using std::list or Boost is that this code will be used in embedded projects and therefore I want to retain control and slash external dependencies as much as possible.

Comment: I am not sure that you are using the term *dynamic dispatch* in the same sense that is used in C++, but other than that, I would reconsider the design. The containers in the standard library are efficient, probably more than what you can do. Having a container of unrelated things is often an indication of a deeper issue in the design, and yielding a *null* object may not be a good idea either (if you want reduced code a function that returns whether it was found is probably more efficient than the alternative checking the runtime type of the object).

Comment: Thank you all for help. 
@David Rodríguez - dribeas Yes, you are right about my use of _dynamic dispatch_. The fact that std::list exhibits undefined behaviour for example when front() is called on an empty container might suggest that this problem is non-trivial to solve in C++ in general.
I am fully aware that having a container of unrelated things is a design smell. On the other hand that idea of returning either a value or nothing is useful in some places.

Comment: @bfo: It can be implemented, the question is whether you want to do so. The trivial approach to this would be having accessors that yield pointers instead of references and that will generate a null pointer if the element is not there. But that is against the design principles in the standard library, as it adds cost to all uses, including those in which the call is done within contract (call `front()` only when `!empty()`). Undefined Behavior at the library level is *good*, not triggering it, but allowing that in the contract if it can provide an advantage.

Comment: ... you can always wrap the existing container with a layer that will detect the emptiness of the container and yield a null pointer (or any other type of sentinel) if there is no element. And using that wrapper will not incur in any additional cost over having the feature in the standard container directly. On the other hand, if the design of the library did that, it would be impossible to recover from the performance costs of the test to determine whether there is a valid object or not, even though you might know that you are only accessing valid objects!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two separate functions.  `Option` has a virtual `nothing()` method, so you can create one non-template function that return whatever `nothing()` returns:

```
bool is_nothing(Option& opt) { return opt.nothing(); }

Nothing n;
Option& an_option() { return n; }

int main(int argc,char** argv) 
{
    if (is_nothing(an_option()))
        ...

    return 0;
}
```

Which, of course, is redundant when you can just call `nothing()` directly:

```
Nothing n;
Option& an_option() { return n; }

int main(int argc,char** argv) 
{
    if (an_option().nothing())
        ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed. Though if a client wanted to add some other functionality that based on a returned type, things would not be that easy.